# javax.jms API not availble to JNLP launched client

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, jnlp

I have a Java swing GUI client.
It is delivered to user's PCs via JNLP in response to a web page request.
It has a javax.jms.MessageListener that listens to a jms.Queue on a remote internet server (glassfish 4) whose Message listener is a MDB.

When I launch the client directly from eclipse, all works well.

But when I launch if from my browser clicking a link to the JNLP filethe client fails to deploy with a NoClassFound for javax.jms.MessageListener.

After many hours it dawned on me that maybe that's because Java JRE doesn't include the JMS API.  And therefore I need to package the JMS classes used by the client in my .ear package.

So I'd truly appreciate anyone telling me if they think I'm on the right track before I start.  And if so confirming where I should put the MessageListener.class in my .ear/.war package.

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

It was a dumb question.  Of course the fix was to package the few JMS .class files I needed in the .jar file the JNLP file downloaded.

Putting in the entire Javax.jms.jar file was unthinkable since it had to be downloaded with the client.

For other newbees all it took was changing the jms.jar to jms.zip to extract the entire API in .class format.  Then repackage only what I needed.